# Italy visa after Marriage

Tags: marriage

I want to apply for spouse visa after marriage . But in marriage certificate (Nikkah Nama) my wife home adress is change because she is from italy .. in her id card there is two adress one is italian where she is living right now and other adress is from Pakistan (Gujrat city) . But our marriage took place in Lahore and thats why our marriage certificate ( nikkah nama) registered in lahore. 
Now in marriage certificate my wife adress is changed on her reletive adress. 
So here is my question is there will be any issue of home adress on marriage certificate at the time of applying documents to embassy ???

Comment: "Now in marriage certificate my wife adress is changed on her reletive adress." I did not get this statement. Your wife has two addresses on her id cards? What are these id cards? And she has a third address on her marriage certificate?

Comment: In overseas italian card she has 2 adress one is italian and other one is pakistan city (gujrat). But our nikah held in Lahore city because i live in lahore.. so in marriage certificate my wife adress is changed ...

Comment: I doubt anyone will pay much attention to the addresses.  People move.  Documents are issued at different times.  The critical data are name, date and place of birth, and (if they are listed) biographical details of parents.

Comment: I appreciate for your response ...